# AngularJS Service InterDependency to pass auth token to Http Header

Tags: authentication, angularjs

I have created three services, OpenApi, SecureApi, and TokenHandler. I want to use TokenHandler Service from SecureApi Service. When authentication will happen controller code will set token in TokenHandler.Set() method. and I want SecureApi to cal tokenHandler.get() as below. Is it Possible. Right now I am getting below error:-

EDIT:- fixed below error (updated the code below too, but my token is still not getting through as part of header :()

Unknown provider: tokenHandlerProvider <- tokenHandler <- SecureApi

Code:-

```
/* Services */
angular.module('MyApp.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('OpenApi', function ($resource) {

        var openApi = $resource(
            '/api/:controller/:id',
            [],
            {
                postLogOn: { method: 'POST', params: { controller: 'Account' } },
                postCustomer: { method: 'POST', params: { controller: 'Employee' } }
            }
        );
        return openApi;
    })

.factory('TokenHandler', function () {
    var tokenHandler = {};
    var token = "none";

    tokenHandler.set = function (newToken) {
        token = newToken;
    };

    tokenHandler.get = function () {
        return token;
    };
    return tokenHandler;
})


   .factory('SecureApi', ['$resource', 'TokenHandler', function(res, tokHandler) { 
       var secureApi = $resource(
        '/api/:controller/:id',
        [],
        {
    getInsightCustomer: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'MyCustomer' }, headers: {Authorization_Token: tokenHandler.get()} }
        }
    );
       return secureApi;
   }]);
```

Comment: In your SecureApi service the TokenHandler service is called tokHandler yet in the getInsightCustomer you're calling tokenHandler.get(). Should work with tokHandler.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer of this in AngularJS googlegroups:-

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/angular/jfttVnvga9M

It was a syntax error in above code.

You TokenHandler service has an upper case T but your SecureApi service is "requesting" tokenHandler with a lower case t.  Generally it is better - and essential if you are going to minimize you js to use the array injection format, which also then allows you to use anything you like as a parameter name for that service.  For example:

.factory('SecureApi', ['$resource', 'TokenHandler', function(res, tokHandler) {
 ...
}]);