# Provide default parameters automatically with $resource?

Tags: angularjs, api, http, rest, alfresco

I'm creating a simple AngularJS app that uses Alfresco as back-end over the provided [REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/RESTful-Repository.html).

Firstly, authentication is performed through the appropriate service which returns a token (`alf_ticket`) and that token must be sent as a URL parameter in the subsequent requests after a successful authentication.

As far as I'm concerned, the Alfresco REST API doesn't support to receive the token as part of the HTTP headers; that would be best option though, since it would be straightforward to solve the issue by configuring $http defaults for instance, just to mention one options I can think of.

In this scenario, I'm afraid I can only send the `alf_ticket` token in every request to the back-end as a parameter, for example:

```
GET /alfresco/s/api/people/admin/preferences?alf_ticket=TICKET_f79aa9eb2f839cefd1e1c7e4f579379ec06c33ed
```

I'm aware of [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) provides a mechanism for default parameters, but these are specific defaults for every instance of $resource.

So far, I have been thinking of the following approaches:

1. Using parametrized URLs for each $resource instance (e.g. `/alfresco/s/api/people/admin/preferences:alf_ticket`); then provide through `parameterDefault` the appropriate function that gets the token from the current session data.
2. Something similar to the approach described in [this blog post](http://nils-blum-oeste.net/angularjs-send-auth-token-with-every--request/), originally inspired by this other [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176330/angularjs-how-to-send-auth-token-with-resource-requests). But I find it slightly intrusive, so probably I'd go with option 1.

Ideally I would be looking for a global configuration for [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) or [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), similar to the way you can configure default headers (`$httpProvider.defaults.headers`), but I'm afraid such functionality is not provided by either of both services...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an $http interceptor.

Create a factory function which reconfigures the request for any URL, adding the auth token to the parameters only if it is set:

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function (Auth) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      if (Auth.token) {
        config.url =  URI(config.url).addSearch({'_auth_token':Auth.token}).toString();
      }
      return config;
    }
  };
})
```

(Note that I am using [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) to add the parameters, since I patterned my answer after [this blog post](http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/), where the author uses it as well)

Pass `$httpProvider` into your `config` block, and push the name string of your interceptor service into its `interceptor` array:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
})
```

Any `$http` requests (including those wrapped by `$resource`) will be intercepted and modified, if appropriate, before the browser executes them.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4AY9xDB6m9ugLCTDilC?p=preview)

Comment: Great answer, that looks a more than suitable solution. Thanks.