# set query param with all http request angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs

How can i pass query parameter with all my angular http reuqest.
how this can be setup in angular config?

eg
`http://localhost/getName`    -  `http://localhost/getName?proxy=myname`

`http://localhost/getList?type=delete`  -  `http://localhost/getList?type=delete&proxy=myname`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742561/provide-default-parameters-automatically-with-resource/23744333#23744333