# How can I configure $http to send an application ID on every request?

Tags: angularjs

I need to send an application ID from my angular app to my api with every request. This will most likely be sent as a parameter or in a header. How can I configure $http to send this with every request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a property on `$http.defaults.headers`:

`$http.defaults.headers.common['My-Header'] = 'value';`

Angular docs: [Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#setting-http-headers)

Comment: This seems like the right solution but it's currently throwing this error 2
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/items. Request header field My-Header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Do I additionally need to set it as an allowed header? and is there a way to set default params or body values?

Comment: Yes, it seems you need to set a response header for your OPTIONS preflight request to indicate that your special header is allowed during the actual request: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header

Comment: To send default params or body values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742561/provide-default-parameters-automatically-with-resource/23744333#23744333

Comment: I'm still trouble shooting the Access-Control-Allow-Headers, but method of setting params will do the trick for this. Thank you! The blog post linked in that question gave me a much better understanding of http interceptors.