# How to share a token between factories?

Tags: angularjs

I have a LoginFactory which returns an `auth` object with a `token` as a part of it. I need to set this token in the header of any REST API call I make, post the user logging in.

What is the best way to share this token across factoires so that the value can be used in said factories?

I tried using angular.module.value but this does not seem to work. (The value never gets set.)

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176330/angularjs-how-to-send-auth-token-with-resource-requests

Comment: @user3644619: This helps in adding a custom URL query param. This solution is not amenable to add a custom header.

Answer (score 0):

in your factory make two method

```
_gettoken(){

return token;
}
_settoken(token_temp){
  token=token_temp;

}
```

now use this factory method to use it any where

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

```
var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        **config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;**
    }

    return config;
}

var _responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}

authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
```

}]);
For more details,
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Thanks. That helps a bit. I'm using $resource and I had to hack this code to get it to work.

Comment: Did you get solution for your problem?

Comment: Did you get solution for your problem?